# Python Find Strings in txt file writing in new file in specific form

Tags: python, string, find, text-files

I want my python program to search for some specific portion of strings in a text file and write them into a new text file.

I have a txt-file in this form.
Input-Text-File:

```
… different text
… different text
… different text
*
    <http://webadress.com/test.jpg>
    *Part ID:* 1234567
    *Design ID:* 54321
    *Part Name:* Test Object x2
    *Category:* Objects
    *Colour:* Yellow
    … different text
    … different text
    … different text

  *
    <http://webadress.com/test2.jpg>
    *Part ID:* 1234566
    *Design ID:* 54322
    *Part Name:* Test Object v4
    *Category:* Objects
    *Colour:* Red
    ... different text
    … different text
    … different text
  *

And so on…
```

I want to get out the following informations in following form.

Output-Text-File:

```
[http; Part ID; Design ID; Part Name; Category; Colour]
[webadress.com/test.jpg; 1234567; 54321; Test Object x2; Objects; Yellow]
[webadress.com/test2.jpg; 1234566; 54322; Test Object v4; Objects; Red]
```

Can you help me please.

Comment: That's a weird output format, better use json here.

Comment: Have you tried using Regular Expressions?

Comment: Are those asterisks really in your file, or were you just trying to make those parts look bold using markup?

Comment: those asterisks are in this file. Its an generated txt-File.. thats the reason why I want to extract those strings... And I've edited the output-File format it was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to give some general advice. Since your input format as well as your output format seem to be some kind of proprietary (or at least non-standard) formats (as opposed to XML, JSON, YAML, ... or even CSV) there is nothing you can do other than implementing these formats yourself.

I'd start parsing the input file format into Python objects. It looks like your input file contains multiple data sets, whereas each data set represents the same type of data, just with other values. Define yourself a class that represents this data type. Instances of this class can conveniently store one data set of the input data. Parse the input file (use Python's powerful string methods or even regex for collecting information) and create instances of your data class on the fly. You'll end up having a list with objects containing your input data.

In a second step, iterate through that list of objects and write your output file in the desired format. Again, you will probably make heavy use of Python's string manipulation/formatting/construction methods.

This kind of abstraction will help you isolate the different components of the problem and keep the solution understandable, clean, maintainable.